# PivotFilters.add no longer working in my spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

This code has always worked in the past. Nothing has changed in the workbook and I have verified that all referenced data is formatted correctly.  Any idea what would have "broken" this?  It no longer applies the "between" filter to the dates in the pivot tables.

Verified pivot tables work when manually altered.  Checked fields in data table to make sure nothing has changed and there is no corrupt data entered.

```
    StartDate = Sheet17.Range("D5").Value
    EndDate = Sheet17.Range("D6").Value

    Set pt = Sheet6.PivotTables(1)
    Set ptF1 = pt.PivotFields("Est closing Date")

    ptF1.ClearAllFilters
    ptF1.PivotFilters.Add _
        Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=StartDate, Value2:=EndDate

    Sheet17.Range("M10:Q999").ClearContents
    pt.TableRange1.Offset(4, 0).Copy
    Sheet17.Cells(10, 13).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Set pt = Sheet6.PivotTables(2)
    Set ptF1 = pt.PivotFields("Funds Date")

    ptF1.ClearAllFilters
    ptF1.PivotFilters.Add _
        Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=StartDate, Value2:=EndDate

    Sheet17.Range("A10:E999").ClearContents
    'omit copying the top row of the PivotTable:
    pt.TableRange2.Offset(4, 0).Copy
    Sheet17.Cells(10, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Fill in dates
    For ii = 11 To 100
        If (Me.Cells(ii, 1) = "" And Me.Cells(ii, 2) <> "") Then
            Me.Cells(ii, 1) = Me.Cells(ii - 1, 1)
        End If
    Next

    'Fill in dates
    For ii = 11 To 100
        If (Me.Cells(ii, 8) = "" And Me.Cells(ii, 9) <> "") Then
            Me.Cells(ii, 8) = Me.Cells(ii - 1, 8)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's about date formatting. Please try to ensure, that the dates are formatted correctly, e. g. by this:

```
ptF1.PivotFilters.Add2 _
    Type:=xlDateBetween, _
    Value1:=CStr(CDate(StartDate)), Value2:=CStr(CDate(EndDate)), _
    WholeDayFilter:=True
```